# In python, is "args = [temp[n] for n in array(index)]" doing a check of temp[n]?

Tags: java, python, for-loop

I am converting from Python into Java.

My question is what is the 'args' doing?

```
args = [this.scrath[c] for c in this.connections(n)]; //Python
```

Is it:

```
[this.scrath[c] //get data at index c of this.scratch[]

for c in // for number of c in connections

this.connections(n)]; //connections to ANN_Neuron n
```

In which case is "this.scratch[c]" checking the data matches c in "this.connections(n)"?

```
this.scratch = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputValues, this.scratch.length-this.input_length, this.scratch.length+1); //JAVA

//inputValues given as negative values.
for (int i=0; i<this.scratch.length; i++){
    this.scratch[i] = inputValues[i]*-1;
}

//loop through the active genes in order
for (ANN_Neuron n : nodes){
    if (n.active){
        float func = n.function;
        for (ANN_Connection c : n.connections){
        //Argument here!!
        }
    }

    args = [this.scrath[c] for c in this.connections(n)]; //Python

    //apply function to the inputs from scratch, save results in scratch
    this.scratch[n] = function(*args);
}
```

Comment: It looks like args is a [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
args = [this.scrath[c] for c in this.connections(n)]
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
args = []
for c in this.connections(n):
    args.append(this.scrath[c])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking at it backwards.

```py
# Python:
args = [f(x) for x in iter]
```

is analogous to

```
// Java:
List<Type> args = new ArrayList<Type>(iter.size());
for (Type x : iter)
    args.add(f(x));
```

So in `[f(x) for x in iter]`, `x` gets assigned to each element of `iter`, `f(x)` is evaluated, and the results are collected in a list.

Answer (score 2):

`[a for b in c]` is a list comprehension. It produces a list by going through every element in the list (or other iterable) `c`, calls that element `b` and then evaluates the expression `a` and puts the result in the resulting list.